# Dispersion Relation for one dimensional monoatomic lattice in Kronig-Penny model and in Tight-Binding Approximation model

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory, dispersion, tight-binding

In the tight binding approximation model, we have the dispersion relation for a one-dimensional atomic lattice given as:

$$E(k) = E_0 - \alpha - 2\beta \cos(ka)$$

Here, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive constants, i.e., overlap integrals.

In the book, they have plotted the E vs. k diagram, and the difference between the maximum value of E and the minimum value of E represents the top and bottom of the band.

However, I am wondering why we have only a single cosine curve for the graph between E vs. k in the tight binding approximation model. A single curve implies that we have only one energy band.

In the Kronig-Penny model, for a one-dimensional monoatomic lattice, when we plot the E vs. k diagram, we obtain multiple energy bands.

Below are the E vs k diagram for 1D monoatomic lattice according to Tight Binding Approximation model and according to Kronig Penny model.
[image: E vs k diagram for 1D monoatomic lattice in Tight Binding Approximation model]

[image: E vs k diagram for 1D monoatomic lattice in Kronig Penny Model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each  band is composed of  spread-out versions of an  eigenstate/eigenvalue of the  atoms in each unit cell (or period). The spreading in energy is  due to  level repulsion arising from the tunnelling from each unit cell (or period)  to its neigbours.  Thus (assuming no degeneracy) there will be as many bands as there are states in each unit cell. For the one-dimensional  tight binding model there is only one state per period; for the K-Penney model there are as many bands as there were bound states in each potential well (plus one big band for the unbound states).

The total number of states *within* each band is equal to the number of unit cells in the whole crystal or system.